# Techniques for finding UMVUEs

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance, estimators, umvue

I'm learning about the different techniques available to find the UMVUE such as Rao-Blackwell and Lehmann-Scheffé theorems. My question is how to know when is better to use one method from the other and also when it is considered better to look for an alternative one instead of the two theorems? Are there some considerations i should keep in mind when picking one?

Comment: Outside exponential families, [there are very few cases when UMVUE exist](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2018/01/18/best-unbiased-estimators/).